# How to insert linked MySQL data to a <div> using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Relatively new to the forums here but I have been helped out tremendously so far by the community. I am currently working with a MySQL database from which I am trying to feed info to a webpage formatted with HTML and CSS.

I am trying to `SELECT` data from my `my_db.events` table and input select data into specific `<div class>`'s and then have this action repeat for every row of info in the `my_db.events` table. This is the PHP function I wrote to perform this task:

```
function filldiv() {
    $loopResult = '';
    $events = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM my_db.events'); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($events)) { 
        $loopResult = ' 
            <div class="maineventfeed"> 
                <div class="eventbox"> 
                    <div class="eventtitle">'.$row['eventname'].'</div> 
                    <div class="eventdate">'.$row['month_id'].'</div> 
                    <div class="eventvenue">'.$row['venue_id'].'</div> 
                    <div class="eventinfo">'.$row['eventdescription'].'</div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        '; 
    } 
    echo $loopResult;
}
```

And here is the html/php document linked to this function:

```
<div id="maincontent">
<div id="eventfeed">
<div id="mainpagecontainer">
</div>
    <div id="maineventfeed">
         <div class="eventbox">
            <div class="eventboxicon">
            </div>
            <?php filldiv() ?>
            <div class="eventtitle">
            </div>
            <div class="eventdate">
            </div>
            <div class="eventvenue">
            </div>
            <div class="eventinfo">
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm really uncertain how to input my function from a separate php file into my divs. I have attached the php file at the top of the html/php document like this `<?php include_once 'get_func.inc.php';?>` and I know that document successfully connects to the DB. It's just a matter of where to put the `<?php filldiv(); ?>` function inline on the HTML/PHP document. Or if this method of performing the function is even possible.

There is a second part to this question. I also am looking to further filter the results that I `SELECT` from my `my_db.events` table through relating them to other tables with identical information. For example: I essentially want to perform a statement that will take the `venue_id` column and cross reference it with the `my_db.venues` table and populate the information from the `name` column of that table in my `<div class='eventtitle'>` instead. I believe the statement would look like this?: `SELECT events.venue_id, venues.name FROM my_db.events, my_db.venues WHERE events.venue_id=venues.venue_id` I'm just not sure where and how to go about putting this into my php script.

EDIT: As per a request in the comments I have included the structure of my `my_db.events` and my `my_db.venues` table. If there is any other information required please let me know! Thanks.

```
describe my_db.events
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+---------------+
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra         |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+---------------+
| events_id        | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment|
| eventname        | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| eventprice       | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| eventdescription | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| eventtype_id     | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| eventsubtype_id  | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| venue_id         | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| neighbourhood_id | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| minute_id        | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| hour_id          | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| time_id          | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| month_id         | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| day_id           | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| year_id          | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
| event_created    | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |               |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+---------------+

describe my_db.venues
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+---------------+
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra         |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+---------------+
| venue_id         | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment|
| name             | varchar(75)   | NO   |     | NULL              |               |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+---------------+
```

If anyone has run into similar issues or has any insight as to how to perform these functions that would be a huge help. Thanks a lot you guys have been awesome so far!

VP

Comment: can you show us your table structure for your `venues` and `events`

Comment: @Viscocent for sure! I'll add them to the main question.

Comment: @Viscocent finally got them up. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your PHP function should be:

```
function filldiv() {
    $loopResult = '';
    $events = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM my_db.events'); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($events)) { 
        $loopResult .= ' 
            <div class="maineventfeed"> 
                <div class="eventbox"> 
                    <div class="eventtitle">'.$row['eventname'].'</div> 
                    <div class="eventdate">'.$row['month_id'].'</div> 
                    <div class="eventvenue">'.$row['venue_id'].'</div> 
                    <div class="eventinfo">'.$row['eventdescription'].'</div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        '; 
    } 
    echo $loopResult;
}
```

your html and php code should look like this:

```
<div id="maincontent">
    <div id="eventfeed">
        <div id="mainpagecontainer">
        </div>
        <?php filldiv() ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

this should answer your second question

```
SELECT * FROM my_db.events e LEFT JOIN my_db.venues USING(venue_id);
```

Comment: thanks! this has helped me generate info to my div with the correct formatting. Now the only issue I am having is getting it to repeat?? I get my first record but the second is not generating. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @velvetpuma this line with `$loopResult =` should be `$loopResult .=` so it will display all results. just copy the php function i made.

Comment: perfect! that worked, got me up and running, I'm loving the knowledge I am picking up.

Comment: @velvetpuma np, happy coding